Route google api interaction through proxy
I just wanted to run this example code for the Gemini API:
import google.generativeai as genai
import PIL.Image
import os

genai.configure(api_key=os.environ["GOOGLE_API_KEY"])
img = PIL.Image.open('path/to/image.png')

model = genai.GenerativeModel(model_name="gemini-1.5-flash")
response = model.generate_content(["What is in this photo?", img])
print(response.text)

But I got this error:
400 User location is not supported for the API use without a billing account linked.

After some research I found out that the free version of the Gemini API is not avaivable in my country. Is there some way to route the requests to the google api through a proxy?
I've already tried a system-wide proxy but it wouldn't fit my use case.
UPDATE:
I fixed it by setting the proxy as an evoirment variable like this:
import os

proxy = 'http://<user>:<pass>@<proxy>:<port>'

os.environ['http_proxy'] = proxy 
os.environ['HTTP_PROXY'] = proxy
os.environ['https_proxy'] = proxy
os.environ['HTTPS_PROXY'] = proxy


# your code goes here.............
genai.configure(api_key=os.environ["GOOGLE_API_KEY"])


I used a vpn when it wasnt working in my country.
